# Python (3.6) (win32) to start Excel with the add-in SAP Analysis for Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, sap-analysis-for-office

I'm trying to replace my VBA code(s) with Python (3.6) and I cannot figure out how to start Excel (2016-64) with SAP Analysis for Excel from Python. Below is the code I'm using.

```
import win32com.client as w32

f_path = "example.xlsm"

xl = w32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(f_path))
xl.Visible = 1 
xl.WindowState = w32.constants.xlMaximized
```

With this method Excel will open however the SAP Analysis add-in (.vsto) does not load. The things I've tried so far:

- Set the `LoadBehaviour` to 3 in regedit for the add-in (so it starts automatically)
- Try to launch the add-in with python in shell
- Include a macro within the Excel file that starts the add-in

If I start the file manually then the add-in loads properly. If I use the last two method then a new Excel instance will be started with the add-in while the file I was trying to use will not have the add-in loaded.
What I found interesting that if I start Excel (without the add-in) and - by using VBA - I start the add-in (with the shell lib) then it loads properly.

Did anyone else had this issue before?